# Of VirtualBox, Chef-dk and Ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, virtualbox

I've been trying to set up a home "lab" so I can further increase my fluency in Chef. While doing this, I've found an area of frustration I'm looking both to understand (likely a VBox cause) and remedy.

The goal is to use my Arch desktop (which hosts VBox) as the workstation for Chef-dk (installed)
Create two Ubuntu VMs (setup and configured): 
- chefsvr (hosts the Chef server)
- chefnode (the node to apply Chef recipes on and manage)

Having spent a while trying to get this all up and running, I noticed that this fails. The error is:

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize': Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout (Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout)
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:57:in `initialize'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `new'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-4.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:233:in `start'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb:186:in `new_session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session.rb:488:in `next_session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/server.rb:138:in `session'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-multi-1.2.1/lib/net/ssh/multi/session_actions.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in sessions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/logging-2.2.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
```

In trying to debug the above, I've added a 2nd nick to the VM's so that the first NIC is now a Host Only Adapter and the 2nd a Bridge Adapter as I want to use my internal DNS server. Traffic seems to pass freely and SSH works all around outside of Chef.

No joy after adding the 2nd adapters.

My next effort was to spin up a 3rd VM and try that as a management node. Instead of Arch I used Ubuntu because I wanted to be as close to the Chef "How-to" as possible. After spinning up and configuring this workstation, everything works as expected.

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated. I'd love to use all the tools on my Arch and not be working totally in VMs.

My guess is that there's some networking adjustment I need to make with VirtualBox, but so far I've been unable to identify any.

Many thanks.

Current Versions (although many others tried historically):

```
VBox 5.2.2r119230
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.4.19 
chef-client version: 13.6.4 
berks version: 6.3.1 
kitchen version: 1.19.2 
inspec version: 1.46.2
```

---

Additional Info:

Specifics:
Physical IP of Host: 192.168.1.98/24
Guest Bridge Adapter Network: 192.168.1.0/24
Guest Host-Only Adapter Network: 192.168.56.0/24

The Chef nodes have an address in each.
Example:

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:6a:49:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.102/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 1035sec preferred_lft 1035secknife bootstrap chefnode --ssh-user mtompkins --sudo --identity-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa --node-name chefnode --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_httpd]'
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe6a:496a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:25:13:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.174/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 73642sec preferred_lft 73642sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe25:1343/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

Add'l #2

Tried bypassing **DNS** by static entries in the host file so trffic would route on the Host-Only subnet. Traffic flows correctly bypassing the bridge but no improvement on trying to bootstrap a node.

Comment: What versions of Vagrant and VBox?

Comment: @coderanger Although on a previous trial I used Vagrant, atm I removed it and have done it all manually so as to simplify/remove possible causes. VBox: 5.2.2r119230 currently - however this condition has persisted for more than a year ... I've only now had the opportunity to come back around to it.